# How to uninstall VUE 4.1.2

Tags: vue.js, npm, vuejs2, vue-cli-4

Okay,

so i thought this is a quite simple task,
i run `npm uninstall -g vue-cli` as an admin but it return `up to date in 0.043s`.

Am not sure what to do to delete properly vue js from my machine.

am running windows 8.1 pro, vue-cli 4.1.2, npm 6.14.4 , node v12.14.1

Answer (score 0):

`npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`

Try this, and that's just remove vue-cli from your dependencies. If the project is vue-based, whether you remove the library or restart new project base.

Answer (score 0):

You should run `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`
according to this: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-to-uninstall-vue-cli-3/74083

Comment: as i mentioned, when i run (npm uninstall ), it return ( up to date ), so this techniclly the problem that am having,  either with @vue-cli or vue-cli or vue or adding --force ,, its just update vue

Comment: Try @vue/cli  with slash.